# Restoring deleted files by rm -r

Tags: bash, mac, terminal

In Mac's terminal, while trying to delete an uncompressed file, I accidentally deleted most of my /usr/local/bin including bash. While searching for solutions to undo the damage, I found that most of the answers involved using bash. Is there a way to restore them without using bash or a place to download precompiled bash binaries?

Comment: Time Machine's good for that kind of thing; or Backblaze, or ...

Comment: @dsstorefile1 I don't think so. My computer has all kind of stuff installed and I don't want to waste them.

Comment: @Tetsujin Excuse me, but sorry I don't have backup

Comment: Then that will be your simplest recourse.

Comment: How did those files get into /usr/local/bin? Homebrew or Ports? I'd start there. Check that... I'd start by either getting an ext HD and scheduling Time Machine or even better paying for a service like Backblaze, then restoring your binaries via brew or ports.

Comment: Also, Apple ships bash by default in /bin/bash, so while it may not be the latest version of bash, you'll be able to work in a terminal until you can restore your previous tools and newer bash.

Comment: @Tetsujin What do you mean?I meant I don't have backup. Those require you to backup!

Comment: @MMB For your first comment, what do you mean by "those files"?
Also, I only found "bashbug" and "batch" related to bash in /usr/bin.

Comment: @Aaron, those files refer to the files & folders you accidentally deleted under `/usr/local/bin`. Also, I wrote `/bin/bash`, not `/usr/bin/bash`. Apple has shipped `bash` with every version of macOS, so it should be there.

Comment: @MMB Thanks. For some reason, I had bash in /usr/bin, but I found another copy in /bin! Yay! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was being stupid. The copy I had in /usr/local/bin was by homebrew, and my default shell was still protected in /bin. Yay!

If anyone finds themselves in a similar situation, then see if your precious shell is in /bin!